# Dynamic height of horizontal FlatList inside vertical FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I was wondering if it was possible to circumvent the behaviour of FlatList always taking the height of the largest item.

I have a vertical FlatList with a nested horizontal FlatList that has items of variable height. At the moment, the List always shows the whitespace to adjust for the highest item.

I was wondering if there was a way to change this. I tried a variety of combinations of `flex: 1` and `flexGrow: 1` but to no avail.